# How to add Apache Tomcat server to Visual Studio Code under Linux?

Tags: linux, java, visual-studio-code, tomcat

I want to add Apache Tomcat servers to the "Tomcat for Java"-plugin in Visual Studio Code. I'm using vscodium under Manjaro XFCE and Tomcat 8 in a virtualbox.

Unfortunately when I'm trying to add a aerver as shown on the marketplace page of the plugin nothing happens after selecting the servers main folder. I checked the logs and tried the `--verbose` option of vscodium, but it is as if the plugin does not generate any output at all.

When I ran `sudo vscodium` I could add a server, but I don't want to run it that way and now I am wondering how to solve this problem? With some Linux user management or via the Tomcats tomcat-users.xml file (which username/password?)?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Sources:
Tomcat for Java Plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adashen.vscode-tomcat